# Date picker is hidden in ag-grid-angular, which is loaded in NgbModal

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, primeng-calendar

On button click an NgbModal modal box will be loaded. The modal is having an ag-grid-angular component.

This grid have a date picker column. I am using primeng date picker.
HTML code for calendar display.

```
   <p-calendar class="ui-datepicker" type="number" dateFormat="dd-mm-yy" monthNavigator="true" [maxDate]=today [style]="{'position': 'fixed', 'overflow': 'visible', 'z-index': '999', width:'200px'}"
        yearRange="1930:2030" yearNavigator="true" showButtonBar="true" [(ngModel)]="dateValue" (onSelect)="onSelectDate()">
    </p-calendar>
```

The problem here is that the date picker calendar is always hidden inside the grid. like this.
How can I solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved, by looking at the CSS property `overflow` of the CSS class `.ag-root-wrapper`.

This class is declared on the `<ag-grid-angular>` directive (see screenshot).
[image]

The solution for me was to include an overwrite of the `overflow` property in the css of the component that includes the `<ag-grid-angular>` directive. (The component where I include ag-grid on my html).

```css
// Put this on the component that includes ag-grid
::ng-deep .ag-root-wrapper {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

The following [Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842085/popup-div-cut-off-by-container-div) helped me to identify the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add appendTo="body" like this:

```
<p-calendar appendTo="body" class="ui-datepicker" type="number" dateFormat="dd-mm-yy" monthNavigator="true" [maxDate]=today [style]="{'position': 'fixed', 'overflow': 'visible', 'z-index': '999', width:'200px'}"
        yearRange="1930:2030" yearNavigator="true" showButtonBar="true" [(ngModel)]="dateValue" (onSelect)="onSelectDate()">
    </p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the calendar popup is being clipped by the container. This is a common issue when using date pickers.

To solve this you need to set the popup element to the document body, the simplest solution for you would be to add `[appendTo]="'body'"` to your calendar component, this is a property which exists on the API of the primeng-calendar.

See this blog for more details on the implementation, as it has an example using primeng and ag-grid with angular: https://blog.ag-grid.com/using-third-party-datepickers-in-ag-grid/#appending-body